# Append multiple lines from one file to another

Tags: excel, awk, sed, grep, notepad++

**Hello Guys,**

I have two files that have same number of lines (503 exactly) and i want to append the contents of one file to the other right infront of them without any space or tab. Let us consider the input file contents are:

**One.txt**

```
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=
```

**Two.txt**

```
one
val_ilu_girl
pacmanhall
four_stars
squares3
```

**Now I want like this:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=one
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=val_ilu_girl
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=pacmanhall
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=four_stars
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=squares3
```

> **Is there a way to do this using anything from `SED` `GREP` `AWK` to `EXCEL` `Notepadd++` etc.?**

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {print $0 a[FNR]}'  two.txt one.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  a[FNR]=$0             ##Creating an array named a whose index is FNR and value is current line.
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                       ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
{                       ##These statements will be executed when 2nd Input_file is being read.
  print $0 a[FNR]       ##Printing current line along with array a value with index of FNR.
}
'  two.txt one.txt      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can u also explain what the pattern is doing exactly.

Comment: @Mujtaba, detailed explanation is already added(few secs ago) please do go through it and lemme know in case of any queries, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

That;s the job `paste` was invented to do:

```
$ paste -d '' one.txt two.txt
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=one
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=val_ilu_girl
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=pacmanhall
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=four_stars
C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename=squares3
```

Comment: I have tried your command and it works but it also append the `'` delimiter after `filename=` like this:   ```C:\Users\Desktop.VG\New-folder\?filename='one```

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong when trying to set the separator (`-d ''`). Just copy/paste exactly what I posted. If somehow it DOES fail for whatever version of `paste` or shell you're running then try `-d ""` or similar. Basically do whatever you have to do in your environment to give `-d` a null string as its argument.

Comment: Yes i am using cmd and intead of `""` i was just copying the above command `''`. Thanks for helping me out.